# Primefaces 8.0 Datatable with Dynamic Model and Columns

Tags: datatable, primefaces, dynamic-columns

I have a primefaces dataTable that displays data from several database tables.  A selection list allows the user to select the specific database table to display.  It works as expected except when the dataTable filtering capability is used.  For example, when a user selects 'DEPT' from the selection list, the dataTable is rendered with data from the DEPT table.  The user can select other tables normally.  However, if the user selects another table called 'EMP' after filtering, the dataTable fails to render with the following exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'example.dto.Dept' does not have the property 'firstName'.
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:576)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:291)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
```

Here's the .xhtml file:

```
<h:form prependId="false">

    <p:outputLabel for="selTbl" value="Select a table:" />
    <p:autoComplete id="selTbl" value="#{mainBean.selectedTable}"
        completeMethod="#{mainBean.filterAuditTables}" cache="true" dropdown="true" effect="fade"
        minQueryLength="3" forceSelection="true" size="35" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{mainBean.onTableSelect}" process="@this" update="@form" />
    </p:autoComplete>

    <p:dataTable id="audTblData" value="#{mainBean.data}" var="row"
        filteredValue="#{mainBean.filteredData}" resizableColumns="true" resizeMode="expand"
        sortMode="multiple">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{mainBean.selectedTable}" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:columns value="#{mainBean.tableColumns}" var="col" sortBy="#{row[col.property]}"
            filterBy="#{row[col.property]}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{col.header}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{row[col.property]}" />
        </p:columns>

    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

MainBean.java:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MainBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // these are used for the audited table selection list
    private List<String> auditedTables;
    private String selectedTable;

    // these are used in the table that displays the audit data
    private List<ColumnModel> tableColumns;
    private List<Auditable> data;
    private List<Auditable> filteredData;

    @Inject
    private AudviewService audviewService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        auditedTables = audviewService.getAuditedTables();
    }

    public List<String> filterAuditTables(String query) {
        return auditedTables
                .stream()
                .filter(t -> t.contains(query.toUpperCase()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void onTableSelect(SelectEvent<String> event) {
        retrieveTableData();
    }

    public void retrieveTableData() {

        List<String> columns = audviewService.listTableColumns(selectedTable);

        // initialize columns for <p:dataTable>
        tableColumns = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();
        for (String col : columns) {
            tableColumns.add(new ColumnModel(col, AudviewUtil.columnToProperty(col)));
        }

        // retrieve data for the selected table
        data = audviewService.getTableData(selectedTable);
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Note that Auditable is an interface implemented by Dept.java and Emp.java.

Comment: Can you post your mainBean definition?

Comment: I have added mainBean to the original post.

Comment: To see if I correctly understand the problem, you have to display different lists of objects that extend Auditable class, and get the error when switching? Moving all the displayed fields into the superclass isn't an option correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I would rather not move all the displayed fields into the superclass.  There are approx. 200 subclasses.

The error when switching occurs when the new model class contains a property that the previous class did not.. Again, this is only if the filtering feature in <p:dataTable> is actually used.  If the user does not enter any filtering constraints, switching to a different list works just fine.

Comment: What if you use a lazyDataModel/

Comment: I am not using pagination so I don't believe there is a need for lazyDataModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the problem is switching from a filtered or sorted datatable to another, if the filtered or sorted column is a field that isn't in the new selected class. An easy solution would be moving all the needed fields into the superclass `Auditable`.

Another approach is separating datatable resetting&updating in two steps, here a possible solution (I replace, for testing purpose, your service with static code, so there could be some errors adapting my solution to your code):

### ***xhtml***

```
<h:form id="formTbl" prependId="false">

    <p:outputLabel for="selTbl" value="Select a table:" />
    <p:autoComplete id="selTbl" value="#{mainBean.selectedTable}"
        completeMethod="#{mainBean.filterAuditTables}" cache="true"
        dropdown="true" effect="fade" minQueryLength="3"
        forceSelection="true" size="35" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{mainBean.onTableSelect}"
            process="@this" onstart="PF('vtWidget').clearFilters()" />
    </p:autoComplete>
    <p:remoteCommand name="btn" process="@this" update="audTblData" />

    <p:dataTable id="audTblData" value="#{mainBean.data}" var="row"
        filteredValue="#{mainBean.filteredData}" resizableColumns="true"
        resizeMode="expand" sortMode="multiple" widgetVar="vtWidget">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{mainBean.selectedTable}" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:columns value="#{mainBean.tableColumns}" var="col"
            sortBy="#{row[col.property]}" filterBy="#{row[col.property]}"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{col.header}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{row[col.property]}" />
        </p:columns>

    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

### ***java***

```
public void retrieveTableData() {

    List<String> columns = listTableColumns(selectedTable);

    // initialize columns for <p:dataTable>
    tableColumns = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();
    for (String col : columns) {
        tableColumns.add(new ColumnModel(col + " header", col));
    }

    // retrieve data for the selected table
    data = getData(selectedTable);
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formTbl:audTblData");
    if (dataTable != null) {
        dataTable.reset();
    }
    PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("btn()");
}
```

Pay attention, if you need also to manage pagination.

Comment: Thank you! My initial testing shows that the fix works. No more problems when selecting another table after using table filters.  However, the columnToggler no longer works... just fyi.  I'll see if I can figure out why.

Comment: One final update for anyone else interested in this use case... the fix doesn't require the <p:remoteCommand> tag in the xhtml file or the "PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("btn()")"; line in the MainBean.java.  When I removed these two lines, the <p:columnToggler> worked again.  

Thanks again to WoAiNii for the solution!